# How do I make it so my page can close or reload but the content wont disappear when i open the page again?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Here is the JavaScript code but I don't think it'll help much because it doesn't have anything that would relate to page reloading since I haven't done it before. every time I reload the page none of the items in a To-DO list save and disappear after it's reloaded.

JS:

```
// Create a "close" button and append it to each list item
var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  myNodelist[i].appendChild(span);
}

// Click on a close button to hide the current list item
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].onclick = function() {
    var div = this.parentElement;
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// Add a "checked" symbol when clicking on a list item
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
}, false);

// Create a new list item when clicking on the "Add" button
function newElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(span);

  for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function() {
      var div = this.parentElement;
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Read this my friend : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage

Comment: @Dael for you case we can do 2 things 
1) first is that you get data from backend thought api
2) if there is no backend then you can store all your data to browser local-storage & set that data so every time you reload page data come from local-storage & if you enter new data just update you local-storage variable

Answer (score 1):

2 modern and easy to use solution are the following:

- Web Storage API. It provides a mechanism for storing and retrieving smaller, data items consisting of a name and a corresponding value. This is useful when you just need to store some simple data, like the user's name, whether they are logged in, what color to use for the background of the screen, etc.
- IndexedDB API. It provides the browser with a complete database system for storing complex data. This can be used for things from complete sets of customer records to even complex data types like audio or video files.

Check examples on this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage

Will edit this answer once I have a PC at reach to include examples.

---

**EDIT:** Here is an example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage#storing_simple_data_%E2%80%94_web_storage

Comment: Thanks! im not really sure what to do so having an example would be great